# Scale docker compose service without impacting other running services

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a number of services in a docker stack, where some are started manually only.

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
services:

  other:
    # ...

  app:
    # ...
    depends_on:
     - db
    deploy:
      replicas: 0

  db:
    # ...
    deploy:
      replicas: 0

  adminer:
    # ...
    deploy:
      replicas: 0
```

I can start `app` and `db` like this:

```
docker compose up -d --scale app=1 --scale db=1
```

If I then start `adminer`:

```
docker compose up -d --scale adminer=1
```

...it will stop `app` and `db` and then start `adminer`. I don't want to stop them.

Is there a way to scale services without impacting existing services?

Comment: Since there are no responses, I assume this is impossible. I added a [feature request](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/10965) to the repo - please upvote it if you need this functionality.